# What does parity operation mean on a vector represented in polar form

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, parity

Recently i studied vector's mathematical meaning (i.e the vectors transforms the same way as co- ordinate system) and our teacher introduced us to parity operation and how vectors transforms under it. A'=P A this operation changed both both x and y co-ordinates .I wanted to know how would parity operation look on a vector reprented by polar co-ordinate form

Comment: What do you expect? The coordinate representation does change what the vector is or does.

Answer (score 1):

The parity operation in cartesian coordinates
$$x\rightarrow -x, y\rightarrow -y, z\rightarrow -z$$
corresponds to
\begin{align}
r &\rightarrow r\\
\theta &\rightarrow \pi-\theta \\
\phi &\rightarrow \phi + \pi
\end{align}
in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Thats actually what i need is there any reference or book in which i can get that in detail to study

Comment: If you draw the picture you'll see  it's obviously correct. Better than a book.

Comment: That is upon parity the r remains same but theta and phi inverses ....and the angle of those are taken with respect to changed co ordinate axes right

Comment: For example remember that $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}$ and you can see how the above relation doesn't change $r$